# Git merge two similar repositories into one (both added conflicts)

Tags: git, github, git-merge

My situation looks like that:

I have two repositories with more or less the same code (let say repo A and B). I would like to pull repo B from repo A.
On repo A I execute following commands:

```
git remote add repoB path/to/repoB
git checkout -b branchB repoB/master
git merge branchB
```

Problem:
I get tons of `both added` conflicts because both repositories consist of many identical files which were added in the first commit and left unchanged.

How to merge this repos without spending whole day on checking if "both added" files have different content or identical?

I would like to merge identical files automatically and leave only files which has different content for manual merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe someone can offer easier way to do this but the only option I found is:

- add repoB as new branch to repoA

```
    git remote add repoB path/to/repoB
    git checkout -b branchB repoB/master
```

- rebase repoA to the initial commit (repo A and B has similar initial commit)

```
    git rebase -i --root
```

- merge with branchB on its initial commit

```
    git merge -Xours SHA_OF_BRANCHB_INITIAL_COMMIT
```

- rebase repoA to current state

```
    git rebase --continue
```

- merge repos as normal

```
    git merge branchB
```

Thanks to this solution all common files are merged in the first two commits so I can safely use `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs` in this merge

Answer (score 1):

You could check if a [`git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) strategy would allow you to resolve those conflicts automatically:

```
git merge -Xours branchB
```

Note that would apply to *all* files with conflicts, not just the ones "both added".

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it wasn't successful because I lost a lot of changes from rep B files which were already present in repo A

Comment: @user2041318 does that mean you would loose files? Did that solve the "both added" conflicts though?

Comment: I mean modifications of course. When I executed your command I get successful merge without conflicts whereas I should get some. The result was that files from branchA overrides changes from merged branch.

Answer (score 1):

When merge has to work with a bad base, it gets inaccurate change hunks -- in this case, with the history showing no common ancestor at all, merge's autoresolve starts with every file showing as a single added change hunk.

One thing you could try is grafting the roots together:

> `echo $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 other) \`
>                       `$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)   > .git/info/grafts`
>   `git merge`*`other`*

If that doesn't get good results, just abort the merge and yank the `.git/info/grafts` file.

A general-purpose fallback is

> `git merge --no-commit --strategy ours`*`other`*
>   `git diff ..other | git apply`
>   `git add --patch .`

Comment: +1. The "no common ancestor" case is a good one to mention here.